# disable org.owasp dependency-check-maven upon mvn clean install but enable during mvn clean site

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-check-plugin, owasp-dependency-check

I want to avoid running org.owasp dependency-check-maven when I run `mvn clean install`. On the other hand, I would like it to run on `mvn clean site`.

In my pom file, I have this code:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
    <version>8.4.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <assemblyAnalyzerEnabled>false</assemblyAnalyzerEnabled>
        <formats>
            <format>html</format>
        </formats>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However, as of right now, a whole dependency check is run during `mvn clean install`:

```
[INFO] --- dependency-check:8.4.2:check (default) @ project ---
[INFO] Checking for updates
[INFO] Skipping NVD check since last check was within 4 hours.
[INFO] Skipping RetireJS update since last update was within 24 hours.
[INFO] Skipping Hosted Suppressions file update since last update was within 2 hours.
[INFO] Skipping Known Exploited Vulnerabilities update check since last check was within 24 hours.
[INFO] Check for updates complete (18 ms)
```

which is lengthy, and only needed when the whole site is needed.

How to run dependency check only for `mvn site`, and not `mvn clean install`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin should only be defined in the reporting section actually

Here is the official link to the doc https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-maven/index.html